# Fraction of Budget and Application request limit reached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api

I am a little confused on the Facebook rate limits and need some clarification.

To my knowledge each application gets 100 million api calls per day per application and 600 calls per second per access token.

According to Insight I am currently making about 500K calls per day total for my application however am receiving a large number of "Application request limit reached". Also in Insight I see a table that has a column called "Fraction of Budget". Four of the endpoints listed in there are over 100% (one is around 3000%).

Is Facebook limited per endpoint as well and is there any way to make sure I don't receive these Application request limit reached errors? To my knowledge I'm not even close to the 100M api calls per day per application that Facebook lists as the upper limit.

EDIT: As a clarification, I am receiving error code 4 (API Too many calls) not error code 17 (API User too many calls). https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/

Comment: There is no such 100million limit - the limits are per access token, and making more than one call per access token per second will cause you to hit limits

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ these are the limits: (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day). Also wouldn't a user limit result in a User request limit reached and not an Application request limit reached as I mentioned in the question or are they one in the same? Really what I'm more curious about is the "Fraction of Budget" in which i seem to have blown past at 3000%

Comment: Those are the points at which you need a contract in place with Facebook and are set per application, the implemented technical limits are per user per second or per ad account per second and are far lower (or higher, depending on user count, i guess), the percentage calculation in insights is not necessarily correct, especially if you're using the Ads API as the percentages assume you're not and don't take the much much higher rate limit of the Ads API into account

Comment: Usually the cause of 'application request limit reached' is an incorrect error message being used, an app making calls with the app access token or no access token ( in which case the limit is applied per IP)

Comment: Interesting. I am certain that we are making calls with the users access token after they authenticate. I am adding in some exponential back-off strategy to help mitigate the burst of api calls. Thanks for the information.